# VB Control Naming by Variable

Tags: vb6

```
Dim LineNo as Integer

LineNo = CStr(channel) 'This can have a value of 1 to 100

If LineNo = 1 then
    Text1.Text = "Line one selected"
    Elseif LineNo = 2 then
    Text2.Text = "Line one selected"
    'Etc etc
End if
```

I need to replace the number **"1"** in Text1.Text and every other TextBox with the value of LineNo? For example:

Text{LineNo}.Text

So I would not have to do a repeated "If" and have a smaller one line code like this:

Text{**LineNo**}.Text = "Line " & LineNo & " selected"

How would I do this?

Comment: In addition to the suggestion to use a Control Array, I'd also suggest to look into the SELECT ... CASE statement as a better way of writing that IF statement. I'm not recommending SELECT CASE for this solution, just as a general thing when you want to test a variable for multiple possible values.

Answer (score 4):

Look into a Control array of text boxes. You could have `txtLine()`, for example, indexed by the channel number.

```
 LineNo = CStr(channel)

 txtLine(channel).Text = "Line " & LineNo & " selected"
```

To create the array, set the `Index` property of each of the text boxes to an increasing integer, starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite and relatively small number, you can use a property.  I've used this approach with up to 30+ elements in a pinch.  Super simple, easy pattern to recognize and replicate in other places.  A bit if a pain if the number of elements changes in the future, but extensible nevertheless.

It uses the `Choose` statement, which takes an index N and returns the Nth element (1-based), hence, the check makes sure that N is > 0 and <= MAX (which you would configure).

```
Public Property Get TextBox txt(ByVal N As Long)
  Const MAX As Long = 10
  If N <= 0 || N > MAX Then Exit Property ' Will return a "Nothing".  You could return the bound element if you prefer
  set txt = Choose(Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5, Text6, Text7, Text8, Text9, Text10)
End Property
```

Then, you can simply reference them with the Property, much like an alias:

```
txt(1).Text = "Line 1 text"
txt(2).Text = "Line 2 text"
```

If you have an arbitrary number, then you are likely using a control array already, which is simpler because it can be referenced by Index already, so you can directly reference it.

If neither of these work for you and you have a very large number of controls, you can scan the `Controls` collection in a similar Property, attempting to match `ctrl.Name` with the pattern of your choice (e.g., matching the first 4 characters to the string "Text", thus matching Text1, Text2, etc, for an unlimited number).  Theoretically, this should be future-proofed, but that's just theoretical, because anything can happen.  What it does do for you is to encapsulate the lookup in a way that "pretends" to be a control array.  Same syntax, just you control the value.

```
Public Property Get TextBox txt(ByVal N As Long)
  Dim I As Long
  For I = 0 To Controls.Count - 1 ' Controls is zero-based
    ' Perform whatever check you need to.  Obviously, if you have a "Label" named 
    ' "Text38", the assignment will throw an error (`TextBox = Label` doesn't work).
    If Left(Controls(I).Name, 4) = "Text" Then
      set txt = Controls(I)
    End If
  Next
  ' If you want the Property to never return null, you could uncomment the following line (preventing dereference errors if you insist on the `.Text` for setting/getting the value):
  ' If txt Is Nothing Then Set txt = Text1
End Property
```

Use the same way as above:  `txt(n).Text = "..."`